# Looking how to re-attach "properties" button in the design view in Mono-Develop

Tags: monodevelop

I am currently trying out Mono-develop and I accidentally clicked the "x" button while in the "Properties" window while working in the "design" view....so now all I have is the "Toolbox" and "Document Outline" pads.  Would anyone know how to re-attach the "Properties" pad back to the right side of the "Designer" window ?   I have spent about 3 hours trying to figure out/researching how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's in the main menu: View->Pads->Properties

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out about a minute about and was about to answer my own question.  Thanks alot for the quick response!!!  I appreciate it!